# I collect a lot of data real time through SocketIO events. Should I validate JWT token for every SocketIO event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, jwt

So, I need to collect a lot of data, say 3 units of data every second, by a lot of people. I named the event that collects this data as 'capture'.

I am using JWT for authentication for other less data intensive events.

Now, I'm just worried that validating JWT with every data intensive 'capture' event will be too much load on the sever.

Any suggestions..? Should I validate for every 10 captures. But, then, I have to maintain state. And I'm using NodeJS and maintaining state is not a very easy thing on NodeJS. Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate a JWT with a symmetric key should not be a long-running operation. It does not require database access or additional memory, which you would need to maintain a cache

An alternative is grouping captures in client side in one request

In any case I suggest doing a load and performance test if you have doubts

Comment: Even with symmetric key, it feels 3 per second is going to be heavy. I'm inclined towards maintaining state and checking every 10 seconds or so to decrease the load. This with symmetric key should be very efficient.

Comment: Oh. That's an interesting solution. Batching on client side .

Comment: 3 validations per seconds is not too much. The load depends on the number of concurrent users and hardware performance. Try to group requests if you can and measure if you get the expected performance

Comment: I may have as many as 70,000 users connected concurrently. For 30 minutes or an hour and then none at all.

Comment: 3 units of data per user/second would mean 210.000 requests per second! It is a big number, probably you will need to send data in batch and  asynchronously

Comment: Yes. It is completely async right now. I'm going to try batch requests on client and group by 10 seconds or so depending on the performance.